# Could someone explain to me an error I am getting?

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I have a CGI script that imports cgi, makes an accessor function, and then tries to look up variables. The function is:

```
cgi_form = cgi.FieldStorage()

def get_cgi(field, default=''):
    if cgi_form.has_key(field):
        return cgi_form[field].value
    else:
        return default
```

Which is probably not necessary. But when I try to use it for email, one of the fields I attempted to send from an XHR, it errors out. The line of code triggering the problem is:

```
sys.stderr.write('email: ' + get_cgi('email'))
```

The Apache log has:

```
[Wed Aug 29 11:25:33 2012] [error] [client ::1] Traceback (most recent call last):, referer: http://localhost/professional/calendar-todo/
[Wed Aug 29 11:25:33 2012] [error] [client ::1]   File "/Users/jonathan/mirror/professional/calendar-todo/create_account.cgi", line 26, in <module>, referer: http://localhost/professional/calendar-todo/
[Wed Aug 29 11:25:33 2012] [error] [client ::1]     sys.stderr.write('email: ' + get_cgi('email')), referer: http://localhost/professional/calendar-todo/
[Wed Aug 29 11:25:33 2012] [error] [client ::1]   File "/Users/jonathan/mirror/professional/calendar-todo/create_account.cgi", line 21, in get_cgi, referer: http://localhost/professional/calendar-todo/
[Wed Aug 29 11:25:33 2012] [error] [client ::1]     if cgi_form.has_key(field):, referer: http://localhost/professional/calendar-todo/
[Wed Aug 29 11:25:33 2012] [error] [client ::1]   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/cgi.py", line 580, in has_key, referer: http://localhost/professional/calendar-todo/
[Wed Aug 29 11:25:33 2012] [error] [client ::1] TypeError: not indexable, referer: http://localhost/professional/calendar-todo/
[Wed Aug 29 11:25:33 2012] [error] [client ::1] Premature end of script headers: create_account.cgi, referer: http://localhost/professional/calendar-todo/
```

The client-side code that I was trying to emulate is:

```
document.getElementById('create_account_button').onclick = function()
    {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('POST', 'create_account.cgi');
    request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
    request.send('email=' + encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('create_email').value) + '&password=' + encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('create_password').value) +  '&password_hint=' + encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('create_password_hint').value));
    load_from_request(request);
    return false;
    }
```

Am I sending things appropriately to the XHR in JavaScript? Why, in Python, is the debugging call to get_cgi('email') giving a "TypeError: not indexable" and what can I do to correct that?

Comment: Your request header shouldn't be set to text. it should be: request.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

Comment: Thank you; I've changed the Content-Type and the immediate issue was resolved. Now it's giving an error about premature end of script headers, and I want to investigate whether my program is supplying appropriate output for that input.

Answer (score 2):

The first issue was the request header not being set to `request.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");`.
For the premature headers issue, it is the same concept. Make certain before you print any data out you are printing a content header.

```
print "Content-Type: text/html"
```

Usually I will put the content-type printout at the top of my code, just so I can see anything being sent back to the browser. That way when your code error's out you atleast see what the problem is.